# Problem related to cloud build azure pipelines yaml(Azure devops)

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I use the dotnet pack command in the yml file which packs the code into a NuGet package.

When the pack command runs in the pipeline,it says:
Successfully created a package 'E:\agentname....\45\a\Ayush.search.0.0.4.nupkg'
and when the push command works it says File does not exist
E:\agentname....\45\a/Ayush.search.0.0.4.nupkg.
The problem can be solved to run  by changing the slash in the script- dotnet nuget push $(BUILD.STAGINGDIRECTORY)\ but for cloud builds forward slash is needed.

I use the dotnet pack command in the yml file which packs the code into a NuGet package.

-script: |
dotnet pack Ayush.search/Ayush.search/Ayush.search.csproj --version-suffix --configuration......
I have also used the dotnet nuget push command

-script: |
dotnet nuget push $(BUILD.STAGINGDIRECTORY)/Ayush.Search.*.nupkg --source " " --api-key ...

When the pack command runs in the pipeline,it says:
Successfully created a package 'E:\agentname....\45\a\Ayush.search.0.0.4.nupkg'
and when the push command works it says File does not exist
E:\agentname....\45\a/Ayush.search.0.0.4.nupkg.
The problem can be solved to run  by changing the slash  dotnet nuget push $(BUILD.STAGINGDIRECTORY)\ but for cloud builds forward slash is needed.
What can be done so the forward slash remains and the error gets solved?

Comment: Please consider formating code and errors as `code` or `code block`. It will make the question more readable.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you could use the `dotnet task` instead of script command to do the operation.

```
pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'pack'
    packagesToPack: '**/*.csproj'
    versioningScheme: 'off'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: 'push'
    packagesToPush: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/*.nupkg'
    nuGetFeedType: 'internal'
    publishVstsFeed: ''
```

[image]